# JMeter - smooth out the sample request

Tags: jmeter

I was given a task to create a load test for X users based on some transactions.  When testing, I noticed the samples / sec was erratic.  From the console, I can see some 30 sec intervals are above 40-50 and some below 20 or even < 10.  And thus during the high rates, there were some http 503/504.

I thought of using a Throughput Timer to smooth out the sample rate. However, the information was not provided.  I've request but not available.  They assume that we will just make full use of the client machine provided.  But I did try out the Throughput Controller for different numbers and I do see that the request were consistent and there were no errors from the backend.  Problem is that I don't know what number to use for the actual load test.

1. What causes the erratic sampling rate ?
2. Is using the Throughput Controller the correct way to resolve this ?
3. If not Throughput Controller, is there any other things I can try ?  Like changing some parameters ?  I've already up the Heap to 4GB and extended the timeout to 60 sec and even 120 secs.

Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

If you "don't know what number to use for the actual load test" you could do a [stress test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_performance_testing#Stress_testing), i.e. start with 1 user and [gradually increase the load](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-ramp-up-period) until response time starts exceeding acceptable or errors start occurring, whatever comes the first.

This way you would be able to state what is the maximum load the system under test can handle and what is the [saturation point](http://hd-performance.blogspot.com/2010/05/saturation-point.html) and provide this as the test result to the stakeholders.

HTTP status codes 5xx indicate **server errors**, especially [HTTP 503](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/503) one so it indicates that the application is overloaded and cannot respond properly. So given each virtual user is properly configured to behave like a real user (cache, cookies, think times, etc.) there is no need to artificially limit the requests rate to get results without errors, you need to identify [the cause of the problem](https://www.quora.com/What-is-bottleneck-in-performance-testing) and suggest the ways of fixing it.

Comment: In my case, the number of users is given to us.  So I should step up the ThroughPut to see how many sample/sec the server can support without 503 ?

Comment: [Load testing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_performance_testing#Load_testing) is the process of checking system under test performance under the **anticipated** load. Given you 1. know the expected number of users 2. [Configured JMeter to behave like a real browser](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206733719-How-to-make-JMeter-behave-more-like-a-real-browser) 3. Implemented [think-times](https://medium.com/@malith.jayasinghe/performance-testing-with-a-think-time-64b6b737e3f9) and getting HTTP 5xx errors it indicates that the system cannot handle the load.

Comment: Thanks.  Any reason why the erratic sample/rate in this situation ?  Thanks.